# Handle promise rejection with Chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I have the following validation function checking if a user exists:

```
validate.user = async (user, password) => {
    const matches = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (matches) return user;
    if (!matches) {
        return validate.logAndThrow('User password does not match');
    }
    return validate.logAndThrow('Error in bcrypt compare');
};
```

The following test using Chai should test this:

```
chai.use(sinonChai);
const { expect } = chai;

    describe('#user', () => {
        it('show throw if user is undefined', () => {
            expect(() => validate.user(undefined, 'pass')).to.throw('User does not exist');
        });
```

The error does get thrown, however mocha shows the following in the console:

> 2) show throw if user is undefined
>   (node:18587) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: User does not exist

So my question is, how I can rewrite the test such that it does catch promise rejections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing promise-based functions (async) use [chai-as-promised](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised) plugin:

```
expect(validate.user(undefined, 'pass')).to.be.rejectedWith(Error, 'User does not exist');
```

In this case you do not put `() => validate.user()` into `expect` because it will not return a promise. **`async` functions always return a promise**, so it's enough to just call your method inside `expect` (without wrapping it into a method).

I hope this is clear :) If you have any questions - feel free to ask.

Comment: This seems to be the right solution. No warning anymore, but neither a green checkmark, just "2) show throw if user is undefined" in red with no description.

Comment: Gimme a second I'll check this issue out.

Comment: Could it be that above should be "should.be.rejectedWith(Error, 'Message')? Still no green chark mark though.

Answer (score 1):

Im not totally sure it is mocha that throws that unhandled rejection.

I think it is your bcrypt.compare which is async by nature and uses callbacks. `await` can't really be used out of the box with async functions.

but you can promisify the async calls with nodes `util` library like this:

```
const util = require('util');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const bcryptCompare = util.promisify(bcrypt.compare);
```

Now you can use `await bcryptCompare(password, user.password);` like you intended. please note that i changed the constant after the await call.

Also to handle rejections with `async/await` you should use `try/catch` like this:

```
let matches;
try {
    matches = await bcryptCompare(password, user.password);
} catch(bcryptError) {
    throw new Error(bcryptError);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. There is a typo in the catch block though: bcryptError. However since I still get UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning, I don't think this solves the issue.